# How to access TypeScript typings for Electron’s extended global process object?

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, global

Assume we have a library of functions like the following, intended to run in the Electron main process and access the global NodeJS `process` module:

```
function isMainProcess() : boolean {
  return process.type === ELECTRON_MAIN;
}

function isRenderProcess() : boolean {
  return process.type === ELECTRON_RENDER;
}
```

In Electron, this `process` global has [a bunch of extensions and methods specific to the Electron runtime](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/process). These extensions have a TypeScript definition in the Electron typings file `electron.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Process extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
    // etc...
  }
}
```

But this declaration doesn’t appear to be recognised as a global variable by default in projects (either within VS Code, or when running the TypeScript compiler). So the above JavaScript functions that reference `process.type` give the following error:

> **error TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Process'**

What is the standard way to ensure that the TypeScript toolchain recognises the global `process` module as the interface defined in Electron’s typings, rather than the NodeJS default interface that comes bundled with TypeScript itself?

Comment: Bonus points if you can share a smart method of mocking or stubbing this global process object in TypeScript unit tests.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this?